# Copying read value from txt to a vector

Tags: c++

I want to read values from a txt file (alibaba.txt) and put them into a vector. Then, each time i call the function "inter_arrival", i will return the next value of the vector.

```
int i = 0; 
int tmp = 0; 
vector <int> values;    
    
int inter_arrival()
{
    tmp = i; 
    ifstream inFile; 
    inFile.open("alibaba.txt"); 

    if (!inFile) {
            cout << "Unable to open file";
            exit(1); // terminate with error
        } 
    while (inFile >> x) {
        cout << "values = " << x << endl; 
        values[tmp] = x; //this assigment does not work...
    } 

    i = i + 1;
    
    inFile.close();

    return values[tmp];
}
```

Comment: If your question is about the "// this .. does not work" part of your code: vectors start off *empty* and you need to use `.push_back()` to put `x` at the end of the vector. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: _`values[tmp] = x;`_ Sure this doesn't work for various reasons, but you can simply call `push_back()` or `emplace_back()`.

Comment: .. and if it is about "how can I do this efficiently", then consider reading the file *once*, putting all the values into the vector, and then iterating over the vector (like with the `i` variable).